# Return a variable name after applying a function on a vector in R

Tags: r, variables, object, vector, names

Let's say for example my project has numerous objects which I've placed into a vector.

```
foo <- 10
bar <- 9
pleb <- 4
eian <- 8

pizzaParlor <- c(foo, bar, pleb, eian)
```

By creating the function below, I can quickly determine the tastiest item at this pizza parlor.

```
tastiestFood = function(anyVector) {
    paste("Item #", 
          which.max(anyVector), 
          "of", 
          deparse(substitute(anyVector)), 
          "is the tastiest!")
}

tastiestFood(pizzaParlor)
[1] "Item # 1 of pizzaParlor is the tastiest!"
```

How would I go about getting this output instead?

```
[1] "foo"
```

The challenge I'm encountering is ensuring that the function is written in a way that will work for any numeric vector, of any length, and with differently named objects. Defining a names vector and labeling the vector ahead of time would violate this (I think?).

Thanks ahead of time for your help.

Comment: Well, you can't get a named output without defining names in any form. You need to have any string corresponding to the position of `which.max(anyVector)` to be able to output this string into your `paste()` call.

Comment: `pizzaParlor <- c(foo=foo, bar=bar, pleb=pleb, eian=eian)` ... then (as LeoP. commented) in your function `names(anyVector)[which.max(anyVector)]`

Comment: Thanks for your comment Leo + jogo. My Python colleague could call the variable name directly using dictionary, so I'm was hoping there was something similar in R. From what you're saying, the vector would need to be setup with the names specified from the get-go. If I were given a large quantity of unnamed vectors to work on with objects nested within, it would fantastic if I could call the name directly from the variable name.

Comment: Scratch that. I reviewed the Python method and it's basically the same issue I'm facing with R. It would need to be pre-defined when constructing the dictionary in order for the variable name to be called upon.

Comment: Yeah, I can't see a situation where you would be able to get a variable name from any object without predefining them. My solution below would at least use names when there are any, and only use the position within the object when it is not named.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the existence of names in your input vector within your function, and if there are any, output them, else output the position.

Try

```
ifelse(!is.null(names(anyVector)), names(anyVector)[which.max(anyVector)], 
  which.max(anyVector))
```

in your `paste()` call instead of the current `which.max(anyVector)`.

Data:

```
foo <- 10
bar <- 9
pleb <- 4
eian <- 8

pizzaParlor <- c(foo, bar, pleb, eian)
pizzaParlor2 <- c(foo=foo, bar=bar, pleb=pleb, eian=eian)
```

Function:

```
tastiestFood = function(anyVector) {
    paste("Item #", 
          ifelse(!is.null(names(anyVector)), names(anyVector)[which.max(anyVector)], 
                 which.max(anyVector)), 
          "of", 
          deparse(substitute(anyVector)), 
          "is the tastiest!")
}
```

Output:

```
> tastiestFood(pizzaParlor)
[1] "Item # 1 of pizzaParlor is the tastiest!"

> tastiestFood(pizzaParlor2)
[1] "Item # foo of pizzaParlor2 is the tastiest!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foo <- 10
bar <- 9
pleb <- 14
eian <- 8

pizzaParlor <- data.frame(foo, bar, pleb, eian)

tastiestFood = function(anyVector) {
    paste(colnames(anyVector)[which.max(anyVector)])
}

tastiestFood(pizzaParlor)
```

Output:

```
"pleb"
```

Comment: I thought this would be the one Marco, but one problem. This assumes the data I'm working with was setup as a df from the get-go. If I were stuck in situation where all my data were in the form of unlabeled vectors with nested variables, is there a way to return the variable name? I tried using your logic to convert the vector into a df within the function, but was unsuccessful...

Comment: can you specify your code for this situation for more clarification?